# No sound on Gigabyte Motherboard

Tags: 11.10, sound

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 on a Gigabyte GA-MA785GM-UDH mobo. I have not had speakers hooked up until recently and now I realized there is no sound. ALSA seems to be loaded and the correct output is selected, but still no sound.

Can you help?

Comment: Check if its muted maybe? Try using pulseaudio? (and check its running)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too. I don't know exactly the solution, but it had something to do with some microphone settings. (yeah, really!)

Try to mess around with the microphone settings via System settings > Sound > Input

Comment: Nothing muted. I don't have pulseaudio installed (I don't think-sorry about this...Linux noobie). Should I? When I open "Sound" There is nothing shown under microphone and nothing listed under input device. Is the sound chip (Realtec ALC889A) not being seen?